# Stan syntax to create vector of products from parameters without sampling the product

Tags: stan

I have a latent variable model in which I produce a product term. The product term is the product of two latent variables who's scores are sampled. Currently, my model is sampling the product term. This has drastically increased the number of parameters in my model.

My original model was in non matrix formulation:

```
 vector [N] mueta; 
 matrix [N ,2] xi ;   

 mueta = b1[1] + 
         b1[2]*xi[,1] +
         b1[3]*xi[,2] +
         b1[4]*(xi[,2].*xi[,1]) ;
```

I changed it to a matrix formulation where`xi[,1]` is an `N` length vector of `1s (intercept), xi[,2:3]` are factor scores, and `xi[,4]` is an interaction effect.

```
 vector [N] mueta; 

 xi[,1] = rep_vector(1, N); 
 xi[,2:3] = zi * diag_pre_multiply(sigmaxi,L1)' ;  
 xi[,4] = (xi[,2].*xi[,3]); 

 mueta =  xi * b1 ;
```

The first model does not sample the product of the `xi` matrix, the second formulation does. Is there a way for me to specify this in Stan so that `xi[,4]` is not sampled, and is just a generated value from the product of the sampled scores of the 2 factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I solved my own issue. I wanted to post this answer for others who may have a similar problem.

```
 vector [N] mueta; 

 xi[,1] = rep_vector(1, N); 
 xi[,2:3] = zi * diag_pre_multiply(sigmaxi,L1)' ;  

 mueta = (append_col(xi,(xi[,2].*xi[,3])) * b1) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to formulate this as an answer because I can't format code in a comment.  I'd suggest declaring `xi` one size bigger and calculating this as

```
vector[N] mueta;

xi[ , 1] = rep_vector(1, N);
xi[ , 2:3] = zi * diag_pre_multiply(sigmaxi, L1)' ;
xi[ , 4] = xi[ , 2] .* xi[ , 3];

mueta = xi * b1
```

If `xi[ , 2]` and `xi[ , 3]` are data, then you can also precompute their elementwise product.  So this can be:

```
transformed data {
  vector[N] intercept = rep_vector(1, N);
  vector[N] xi2_3 = xi[ , 2] .* xi[ , 3];
...

  vector[N] mueta
    = append_row(intercept, 
                 append_row(zi * diag_pre_multiply(sigmaxi, L1)',
                            xi2_3))
      * b1;
```

It'd be even better to reorganize the predictors so that you have `append_row(intercept, xi2_3)` defined as a transformed data variable.

It's probably possible to go further and just directly define the elements of `mueta` (`mu_eta`?) without first construting a matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your response @BobCarpenter. XI is in fact not data, but parameters to be sampled (latent factor scores). I got by using append_col(). I agree with your suggestion to reorganize the elements with better naming conventions.